# How to remove child's border around parent?

Tags: html, css

If make table with 9 tds, add borders, how to remove border around parent?

[I need to remove this border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XTHa.png):

[image]

```css
table tr {
  border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="td"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You approach it the wrong way. You should look into `border-collapse`

Comment: `border="0"` will make it won't show border

Comment: @lucumt i tried but doesnt work

Comment: Oleksandr, could you edit the snippet I made from your code so that it recreates the problem you describe, and show?

Comment: @tacoshy but how to remove border around parent?

Comment: you could try to use `tr:first-child>td`,`tr:last-child>td`, `td:first-childl`, `td:lasst-child`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.border-none {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
}

.border-none td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.border-none tr:first-child td {
  border-top: none;
}

.border-none tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.border-none tr td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.border-none tr td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="border-none" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="td"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Border-collapse [Border Collapse](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp)

```css
table,
tr,
th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="td"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```